how to authenticate the application with the refreshToken, accessToken , IDToken?
the application is developed by using aws cognito,
after Getting the three Tokens (refreshToken, accessToken , IDToken) from Amazon Cognito using Postman,
i want to use the application without login, using tokens,
please give me solution for this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
